# How to show a specific frame of a GIF image in C#?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, gif, animated-gif

I want to show a frame of a gif image. I searched and found that the following code should work, but it doesn't work. it detects the number of frames correctly but it shows the whole frames of gif instead of the specified frame. thanks everybody.

```
Image[] frames = new Image[36];
Image GG = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\TEST C#\TEST2frame2\chef.gif");
FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(GG.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
            // Number of frames
int frameCount = GG.GetFrameCount(dimension);
label1.Text = frameCount.ToString();

            // Return an Image at a certain index
GG.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, 1);
frames[1] = ((Image)GG.Clone());
pictureBox1.Image = frames[1];
```

Comment: I was able to replicate the same issue. Indeed, the entire animated gif is displayed instead of a single frame. If you find a solution, plz post it for the community benefit.

Comment: Dear Ali,The ba__friend's answer does work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your own code up until the call of SelectActiveFrame() and after that change to this lines:

```
frames[0] = new Bitmap(GG);
pictureBox1.Image = frame[0];
```

This should do the trick. Please do not forget do dispose the created Images.

Answer (score 3):

Oh it works, but not as you expect it to.

When you set an active frame of a gif image it actually restarts its animation from that frame. You have to stop it when you change a frame, by setting the `pictureBox.IsEnabled` to false, for instance. Try the following code

```
private Image img;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\TEST C#\TEST2frame2\chef.gif");
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dim = new FrameDimension(img.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
    img.SelectActiveFrame(dim, 1);
    pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Try pressing the button in different moments and you will see that the active image frame will change.

Comment: Mr. Janacek I am grateful of you. from your answer I knew how active frame method works. Your answer was helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @MTK Thank you for your kind words. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by checking the green sign below the answer score (<0>), please.