# How to set a extracted gif image to a picturebox in C#?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have been trying to teach myself `C#`and in order to teach myself I have been developing a simple game that has two superheroes attack one another using gifs as the animation for the actions.

I have been trying to figure out a work around to have the `gif` loop once and then set the last image as a still image.

I created a function that extracts the frames and returns an `Image` array.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A method that extracts the frames of a gif.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original_gif">The original gif</param>
    /// <returns>Array of image frames</returns>
    private Image[] GetFrames(Image original_gif)
    {
        ///Get the frame count of the gif
        int number_of_frames = original_gif.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

        ///New image array to store the extracted frames
        Image[] frames = new Image[number_of_frames];

        ///Loop through the gif and store each frame in the frames array
        for (int index = 0; index < number_of_frames; index++)
        {
            original_gif.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, index);
            frames[index] = ((Image)original_gif.Clone());
        }

        return frames;
    }
```

When I try to loop through the `Image` array and set the last element to the `picturebox`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A method that changes the hero picture box to standing
    /// </summary>
    private void SetStandingImage()
    {
        ///Extract images from the gif
        Image[] frames = GetFrames(Properties.Resources.captain_motion_standing);

        ///Loop through the frames displaying each image once
        for (int index = 0; index < frames.Length; index++)
        {
           ///Set the current image to the hero picture box
            hero_picture_box.Image = frames[index];
        }
        ///Set the last frame of the gif as the hero picture box
        hero_picture_box.Image = frames[frames.Length - 1];
    }
```

The `Image` in the `picturebox` does not get set to the last frame of the array. The `picturebox` keeps showing the gif animation that is looping.

Even if I comment out the loop and just set the last image to the `picturebox` it displays the gif that is looping.

How would you extract images from a gif and set the last image to a `picturebox`?

Comment: Did you [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874353/how-to-show-a-specific-frame-of-a-gif-image-in-c) ?  The active frame doesn't look right, as it will change while the gif displays and setting it restarts the animation.

Comment: Thank you for the solution @TaW. Most of over looked that post. Changing `frames[index] = ((Image)original_gif.Clone());` to `frames[index] = new Bitmap(original_gif);` and now have full control over the images in the image array.